# Create range bins in hive for histograms

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-query

I have a data set which contains students_id and their ages. I want the marks should be arranged in a range or bin with the bucket size of 10.

```
stud_id    ages
101        11
102        13
103        21
104        25
```

Similarly i have date for more number of records. this has to be arranged with a bin size of 10.

The Expected output is:

```
stud_id     ages_bin
101         11-20
102         11-20
103         21-30
104         21-30
```

I tried simple case statement in hive.

```
select stud_id,
case when ages between 0 and 10 then '0-10'
when ages between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
when ages between 21 and 30 then '21-30'
when ages between 31 and 40 then '31-40'
when ages between 41 and 50 then '41-50'
when ages between 51 and 60 then '51-60'
when ages between 61 and 70 then '61-70'
when ages between 71 and 80 then '71-80'
when ages between 81 and 90 then '81-90'
when ages between 91 and 100 then '91-100'
when ages between 101 and 110 then '101-110'
when ages between 111 and 120 then '111-120'
when ages between 121 and 130 then '121-130'
when ages between 131 and 140 then '131-140'
when ages between 141 and 150 then '141-150'
else NULL end as ages_bin
from students
```

Is there any simple way to have the binned data with bucket size 10?

can someone help me in writing a simple code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one simple method to arrange the range of bins for histogram. Here is the code:

```sql
select stud_id,floor((ages)/10)*10 as strt_range,
floor((ages)/10)*10+9 as end_range from students
```

This produces the following output:

```
stud_id     ages_bin
101         10-19
102         10-19
103         20-29
104         20-29
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should be able get u the bins in bin format :

```
select stud_id, concat(cast(floor((ages)/10)*10 as string),'-',
cast(floor((ages)/10)*10+9 as string)) from students
```

to be able to get appropriate output, it would better if u group it and order it 
appropriately